# Why assigning a variable to itself memory=memory?

Tags: javascript, shellcode

I am currently analysing some javascript shell-code. Here is a line from this script:

```
function having()
{
    memory = memory;
    setTimeout("F0VTp03Y()", 2000);
}
```

I don't quite understand memory = memory, what's the point of assigning a variable to itself. I would appreciate the help!

Comment: Considering the immediately-following bad practice of passing a string to `setTimeout` (the line should simply be `setTimeout(F0VTp03Y, 2000);`), I'd say the original author may or may not have been drunk...

Comment: Is `memory` defined somewhere higher in the scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason I can think of to assign a variable to itself is variable [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

> Variable shadowing occurs when a variable declared within a certain
>   scope (decision block, method, or inner class) has the same name as a
>   variable declared in an outer scope. At the level of identifiers
>   (names, rather than variables), this is known as name masking. This
>   outer variable is said to be shadowed by the inner variable, while the
>   inner identifier is said to mask the outer identifier. This can lead
>   to confusion, as it may be unclear which variable subsequent uses of
>   the shadowed variable name refer to, which depends on the name
>   resolution rules of the language.

But in your case, the `memory` variable is not a parameter of your function so it doesn't make any sense.